# How to take screen shot for the Failed Tests only after 'Retry'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

In our current framework we are taking screenshots [onTestFailure](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/ITestListener.html). And now we have implemented '[IRetryAnalyzer](http://testng.org/javadoc/org/testng/IRetryAnalyzer.html)' using which are re-running the failed tests.

Here when the test fails for the first time, it is taking the screen shot and keeping it in a folder which indicates 'Failed Test', which may get passed in the next attempt.

When we submit final Automation report, we need to submit screenshots also. In Screenshots folder, currently passed (after re-running) test images are also attached.

**Can we take a screenshot only when the Test has failed Even After Re-running by ignoring the previous test fails.**

Please suggest if there is any other alternative.

Below is the code for Retry

```
@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {

    boolean iFlag=false;
    String resultString = result.getThrowable().toString();

    //Checking for specific reason of failure
    if (resultString.contains("NoSuchElementException") || resultString.contains("TimeoutException") ) {

        if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
            System.out.println("Retrying " + result.getName()+ " test for the "+ (retryCount + 1) + " time(s).");
            retryCount++;
            iFlag=true;
        } 

    } else {
        //making retryCount and maxRetryCount equal
        retryCount=0;
        maxRetryCount=0;
        iFlag=false;
    }

    return iFlag;
}
```

Below is the code for On Test failure

```
private static int retryCount=0;
private static int maxRetryCount=1;


@Override
public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("***** Error "+result.getName()+" test has failed *****");
    String methodName=result.getName().toString().trim();
    //takeScreenShot(methodName);
    driver=TestBase.getDriver();
    if( driver != null && retryCount == maxRetryCount) {
    takeScreenShot(driver, methodName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put both `onTestFailure/AfterMethod` and `retry` methods in same class like Retry or any suitable name. And there  you can define your methods as:

```
private static int retryCount = 0;
private static int maxRetryCount = 2;    
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
String methodname = result.getName();
WebDriver augmentedDriver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);
try {
    if (driver != null
            && ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getSessionId() != null
            && !result.isSuccess() && retryCount == maxRetryCount) {
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) augmentedDriver)
                .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(("./test-output/archive/"
                + "screenshots/" + methodname + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png")));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
            driver.quit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
boolean res = false;
try {
    if (result.getThrowable().toString()
        .contains("NoSuchElementException")) {
    if (retryCount < maxRetryCount) {
        retryCount++;
        res = true;
    } else if (retryCount == maxRetryCount) {
        retryCount = 0;
        res = false;
    }
    } else {
    retryCount = 0;
    }
    return res;
} catch (Exception e) {
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Can i add condition '&& retryCount == maxRetryCount' to the existing OnTestFailure Method which exists in TestListener class

Comment: Yes u can try with that if u have overridden retry method in same code.

Comment: Great i will give a try.

Comment: retryCount is always taking as Zero and unable to take the screenshot on Test fail. Also as im re-running only for the specific exception tests, retryCount and maxRetryCount will not match in other cases where again i cannot take screenshots. Please help

Comment: what u need to do is if ur exception is not matching reinitialize retryCount to equal max. It will fulfill the scenario and allow u to take screenshot. And did u made retryCount to static? If the problem persists...i need to have a check on ur code...Thanks

Comment: dont change max count. And in else part try to make retry to 1 and once u take screnshot reinitialize retry to 0. Hope that might help.

Comment: When i make retryCount=0 after taking the screenshot, again the Failed Method is getting executed And running into infinite loop